# Eclipse LogCat Window does not display

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-adt

I just installed Eclipse 3.8 on my Mac running Mountain Lion. I had the LogCat window opened and hit minimize and it went somewhere...

Now when I hit Window>Show View>Other>LogCat, my screen flickers but there is no LogCat android or anything I can see that indicates it is hidden somewhere. I tried restarting Eclipse to no avail.

Here is a screen shot of my Eclipse environment.

Any ideas where the window is hiding?

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
window > open perspective > other > DDMS
```

on the top right corner of your `ECLIPSE` will popup a small icon named DDMS. Click on that and you will see a line of icons including `logcat`. Drag that thing to bottom left of Eclipse and clik one of the icons then click restore (top right corner).

TADA !!!! your logcat and other views are back.

Comment: Great tip! Save me from a nightmare!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am still not sure where the LogCat window went in the original window. However, I can view LogCat by opening a new window and going to Window>Show View>Other>LogCat.